# Using a loop instead of loads of or statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im trying to get all the dates which a room is booked blocked in the datepicker i got this working with the buildin function isInvalidDate the problem is its static now and i need to add the `|| date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '<?php   echo $items['1'] ?>'` for every item in the array.
Can i do this in some kinda loop? the output from the var_dump is: `

> array(7) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-06-09" [1]=> string(10) "2017-06-10"
>   [2]=> string(10) "2017-06-11" [3]=> string(10) "2017-06-12" [4]=>
>   string(10) "2017-06-14" [5]=> string(10) "2017-06-15" [6]=> string(10)
>   "2017-06-16" }

`
So every time the script will be used the amount of items in the array could be more or less.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      linkedCalendars: false,
      selectPastInvalidDate: false,
      isInvalidDate: function(date) {
      if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '<?php   echo $items['0'] ?>' || date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == '<?php   echo $items['1'] ?>') {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  },
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });



  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to pass full array to a javascript variable and then use javascript array methods

```
var inValidDates = <?php echo json_encode($items) ?>;

$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      ....
      isInvalidDate: function(date) {
         return inValidDates.indexOf(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) >-1;
      },
      .....
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! accepting you the answer when possible